# Using a custom validator to change a label color if data isn't validated

Tags: javascript, webforms

I am wanting to change the color of a label when its associated text box doesn't pass validation. Not getting any results with my current code:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" Text="Your First Name*:"></asp:Label>
<br />
<asp:CustomValidator
    ID="customValFirstName"
    runat="server"
    Text=""
    ControlToValidate="txtFirstName"
    ClientValidationFunction="validateFirstName"
    Display="Dynamic"></asp:CustomValidator>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" MaxLength="50"></asp:TextBox>
```

Javascript:

```
function validateFirstName(sender, args) {
        var firstName = document.getElementById('<%=txtFirstName.ClientID %>');
        var firstNameLbl = document.getElementById('<%=lblFirstName.ClientID %>');
        if (firstName !== "") {
            args.IsValid = true;
        }
        else {
            args.IsValid = false;
            firstNameLbl.style.color = '#FF0000';
        }
    };
```

Any light that can be shed on what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: What is currently happening? Is the function executed?

Comment: Nothing is happening, the target label stays the initial color. As far as I can tell, the function isn't executed. My other javascript functions are running normally.

Comment: Just on a side note, what is the point of the `sender` parameter?

Comment: Just me being a slob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compare the value of the textbox.

Change `if (firstName !== "")` to `if (firstName.value !== "")`

Also add one more attribute to your custom validator markup: `ValidateEmptyText="true"` otherwise empty text won't be validated at all

Comment: I'm still getting no change. Not sure what else it could be.

Comment: Did you change both JavaScript part and ASPX part?

Comment: The ValidateEmptyText part was what fixed it, thanks. You're a champ.